# It doesn't load all the data from .properties file

Tags: java, selenium, intellij-idea, properties, appium

`prop.getProperty();` loads only certain data, if I add something new or change the String name in `.properties` file and code it won't load it.

I am trying to load some data from properties file to include it in `capability.setCapability`

But the problem is some data is loaded some is null, I have tried everything and I gotta wonder is there any limitations on how many variables `.properties` file can handle?

myData.properties file

```
pinCode=123456

osname=Android 9

activationCode=13412741 39313106

user=user123456

device=Android Emulator

name=G5 SE
```

Code

```
System.out.println(prop.getProperty("name"));

System.out.println(prop.getProperty("user"));

System.out.println(prop.getProperty("device"));

System.out.println(prop.getProperty("osname"));

System.out.println(prop.getProperty("activationCode"));

System.out.println(prop.getProperty("pinCode"));
```

Output

```
null
user123456
Android Emulator
null
13412741 39313106
123456
```

Now it should print out "name", "user", "device", "activationCode", "pinCode" and "osname" right?

But it only prints out "user", "activationCode", "pinCode" and "device", I get "name" and "osname" as null.

Note that if I change the name of string in properties file and in code it won't work as well...

For example if I change "pinCode" to just "pin" or "code" it doesn't work.

Please help this is killing me.

Comment: Can you share the code that loads the properties as that's likely to be where the problem is.  There is no limit (as far as I know) on the number of properties.  And possibly dumb question: are you *absolutely* certain you are loading the correct file?

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't load the correct file

A simple test is:

Paths

```
src\test\java\Test.java
src\test\resources\myData.properties
```

myData.properties

```
pinCode=123456
osname=Android 9
activationCode=13412741 39313106
user=user123456
device=Android Emulator
name=G5 SE
```

Test

```
    @Test
    public void testProp() throws IOException {
        Properties prop = new Properties();

        ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
        File file = new File(Objects.requireNonNull(classLoader.getResource("myData.properties")).getFile());

        prop.load(new FileInputStream(file));

        System.out.println(prop.getProperty("name"));
        System.out.println(prop.getProperty("user"));
        System.out.println(prop.getProperty("device"));
        System.out.println(prop.getProperty("osname"));
        System.out.println(prop.getProperty("activationCode"));
        System.out.println(prop.getProperty("pinCode"));
    }
```

Output

```
G5 SE
user123456
Android Emulator
Android 9
13412741 39313106
123456
```